# Getting the Button Type of an Alert from showAndWait() in a Timeline: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing

Tags: java, animation, javafx, controller

I have an `Alert.INFORMATION` in JavaFX with custom "yes" and "no" buttons. In a JavaFX `Timeline`, when reaching a condition, I would like to display this alert with `showAndWait()` and then get what the user clicked to close the alert (either "yes" or "no").

Here is what I have so far.

```
package application;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    String drawingsSelected = "something here";
    ButtonType yesButton = new ButtonType("Yes");
    ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No");
    
    Alert commenceAlert;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        commenceAlert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        commenceAlert.setHeaderText("Warning");
        commenceAlert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesButton, noButton);
        
        Button myButton = new Button("click");
        myButton.setOnAction(e->quickPick());
        
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.getChildren().add(myButton);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    

    //randomly select the rest of the card numbers
    private void quickPick() {
        List<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
        int spotsLeft = randomNumbers.size();
        //add randomNumbers on a time-line
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(100),
                
                e -> {
                    setCardNumbers(randomNumbers.remove(0));
                }
                ));
        timeline.setCycleCount(spotsLeft);
        timeline.play();
        
    }

    //add i to the card
    //at the last addition, call commenceDrawings()
    private void setCardNumbers(int i) {
        System.out.println("adding "+i);
        if(i==4) {
            commenceDrawings();
        }
    }

    //called when the conditions are met to start the drawings
    public void commenceDrawings() {
        commenceAlert.setContentText(drawingsSelected);
        
        Optional<ButtonType> result = commenceAlert.showAndWait();
        
        //player selected "YES"
        if(result.get() == yesButton) {
            System.out.println("you clicked yes");
        }
        else //player selected "NO"
        {
            System.out.println("you clicked no");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing
    at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:328)
    at application.Main.commenceDrawings(Main.java:56)
    at application.Main.setCardNumbers(Main.java:89)
    at application.Main.lambda$1(Main.java:77)
    at ...
```

Edit 1: Pausing the Timeline gives the error:

```
The local variable timeline may not have been initialized
```

```
//add randomNumbers on a time-line
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.millis(300),
                    
                    e -> {
                        timeline.pause();
                        setCardNumbers(randomNumbers.remove(0));
                        timeline.play();
                    }
                    ));
```

Edit 2:
I think it works correctly with this edit to setCardNumbers():

```
    //add i to the card
    //at the last addition, call commenceDrawings()
    private void setCardNumbers(int i) {
        System.out.println("adding "+i);
        if(i==4) {
            Platform.runLater(()-> {
                gui.commenceDrawings();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Sorry, @kleopatra. I've added it.

Comment: thanks :) Yeah, see what you mean (and the error tells us exactly what's wrong) - why do you want to let the timeline running further if you expect input from the user? Instead of just stop or pause it?

Comment: setCardNumbers() has these conditions which are checked after adding a number. If all the conditions are all passed, then commenceDrawings(), the erroring function, is called. If I stop the Timeline before adding the last number, the last number won't be added. Stopping it after will still generate the error (because we're still in the Timeline when we add that last number that calls commenceDrawings()). So, what would you suggest that I do?

Comment: enhance your example to demonstrate the constraints (and please read my comment thoroughly, stop is not the only option ;)

Comment: Alright. Well, I tried pausing the timeline, but I get an error. I've edited the above post to show the changes. As for the conditions, why would you like to look at them? I think all that is relevant is that commenceDrawings() is called in setCardNumbers(). So, I would get the same error if I did not have any conditions. (The error would just occur at the first step of the TImeline.)

Comment: @kleopatra, I think I got it working. You could see the new edit under "Edit 2". Thank you for the help.

Comment: wrong place: don't stop/pause the timeline inside itself, but before showing the dialog and continue playing after you get its result